# Finding maximum subarry sum

Tags: c++

Looking for feedback on a question I solved in C++. It is a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-subarray/) and I used divide and conquer to solve the problem.

> #### 53. Maximum Subarray
>
> Given an integer array `nums`, find the contiguous subarray (containing at least one number) which has the largest sum and return its sum.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input: [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],
> Output: 6
> Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
> ```
>
> **Follow up:**
>
> If you have figured out the \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ solution, try coding another solution using the divide and conquer approach, which is more subtle.

I am looking for feedback in terms of logic and also the implementation. If I search for a C++ solution online, I only see problem solved using arrays and I have used vector to solve to the problem while utilizing iterators.

Any feedback would be great.

Thanks!

````cpp
int FindMaximumSubarray(const vector<int> &vec) {
  if (vec.size() == 1) {
    return vec.at(0);
  }
  int midIndex = vec.size() / 2;
  vector<int> leftArray(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + midIndex);
  vector<int> rightArray(vec.begin() + midIndex, vec.end());
  int maximumSumLeftSubarray = FindMaximumSubarray(leftArray);
  int maximumSumRightSubarray = FindMaximumSubarray(rightArray);
  int maximumSumCrossingSubarray = FindMaximumSubarrayCrossing(vec);
  return FindMaximumNumber(maximumSumLeftSubarray,
                           maximumSumRightSubarray,
                           maximumSumCrossingSubarray);
}

int FindMaximumSubarrayCrossing(const vector<int> &vec) {
  int midIndex = vec.size() / 2, leftSum = INT_MIN, rightSum = INT_MIN, sum = 0;
  for (auto itr = vec.rbegin() + midIndex; itr != vec.rend(); ++itr) {
    sum += *itr;
    if (sum > leftSum) leftSum = sum;
  }
  sum = 0;
  for (auto itr = vec.begin() + midIndex + 1; itr != vec.end(); ++itr) {
    sum += *itr;
    if (sum > rightSum) rightSum = sum;
  }
  if (leftSum == INT_MIN || rightSum == INT_MIN) {
    return (leftSum == INT_MIN) ? rightSum : leftSum;
  }
  return (leftSum + rightSum);
}

int FindMaximumNumber(const int &a, const int &b, const int &c) {
  if (a >= b && a >= c) return a;
  if (b >= a && b >= c) return b;
  if (c >= a && c >= b) return c;
}
```
````

Comment: It would be nice to see a more complete description of the problem as well as a link to the actual problem description.

Comment: For future reviews, remember that it helps reviewers to have a self-contained review, rather than having to infer the missing `#include <vector>` and `using std::vector;` that you've not shown.  An example `main()` is always helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a bunch of unnecessary vector copies. Try passing iterators into `FindMaximumSubarray` instead of a vector.

You can find the max of an initializer list of numbers using `std::max`.

You don't need to pass ints as const refs.

Are you sure this is more performant than a linear solution? What is your reasoning? Can we see your linear version?

Your code looks like it might have potential overflow errors. Maybe that's not important.

Comment: I understand that I am creating several unnecessary vector copies but if I pass iterators how can I calculate the `midIndex`? Or is there a workaround for that?

I have added `std::max` with an initializer. Why should I not pass ints as const refs? I am practising divide and conquer methodology hence I did not implement a linear solution but the above solution.

Comment: You can use std::distance or just the - operator since they're vector iterators to get a integral distance between iterators. 

Ints generally shouldn't be const ref parameters because there's no advantage to it. A reference type is possibly bigger than an int, and it may confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

## Consider the edge cases

The first thing I tried to do was:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << FindMaximumSubarray({});
}
```

This resulted in a stack overflow, since we check for a unitary vector but not for an empty one.

Consider using a larger type for the accumulator, as the sum is liable to overflow if the inputs are large.  Ideally, you'd want to use a type that can represent `SIZE_MAX` times the range of `int`.

## Make good use of `<algorithm>`

Instead of `FindMaximumNumber()`, we can simply use `std::max()`:

```
  return std::max({FindMaximumSubarray({vec.begin(), vec.begin() + midIndex}),
                   FindMaximumSubarray({vec.begin() + midIndex, vec.end()}),
                   FindMaximumSubarrayCrossing(vec)});
```

We can use `std::find_if()` to find the first and last positive values, immediately trimming off parts of the input which will never contribute.

## Other observations

Internal functions ought to have internal (`static`) linkage.

Use the correct type for `midIndex` - it should be a `std::size_t`.  Simply using `auto` would avoid that mistake.

`FindMaximumSubarrayCrossing` contains two code blocks that are almost identical - it may be worth refactoring to reduce duplication.

When we test `sum > leftSum`, that's exactly equivalent (in the absence of overflow) to `*itr > 0`.  That observation may help in identifying a more efficient algorithm.

Using `INT_MIN` as a marker is risky, given that that's a valid input value.

We could just use `std::find_if()` to locate zero-crossings and `std::accumulate()` to total each positive and each negative run.  Then see which runs combine usefully.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have fixed moved from my custom function to `std::max()`.

It also makes sense to change `midIndex` from int to size_t.

I did not understand your point about sum > leftSum.

What would you recommend using if not `INT_MIN`?

Comment: The observation that we only update `leftSum` when we're looking at a positive value is just an observation (not a criticism).  It may help in understanding what we're looking for.  You might be able to use `LONG_MIN` as a marker if `long` is big enough for any sum, but I think it could be clearer to maintain a separate boolean flag.  Or use a `std::optional` - that's the kind of thing it's for, after all.